# Secure http call in Microsoft Access in 2017 ... is there such a thing

Tags: http, security, ms-access, merchant-account

I am coming from a background in Web Development. Have had some classes in MS access about 3 years ago. Currently I am working on a project primarily built using Access. Eventually the program will be expanded to interface with the same database that Access uses in the cloud. Which will then lead to development on a  web project.

My question is its 2017 and I am aware that you can make web calls in Access , but just because I can doesn't mean I should right ? My client/boss would like to implement a credit card processing payment system into his Access application. However I am pushing for this to be something built from the web development side project that will take place later using an API. Any Access developers out there able to suggest whether its a good idea to wait to build this feature later when development has begun on the web project ? Is it okay or secure to make web calls using Access ? Or is there any alternatives to an existing merchant service that can interface with Access ? Any advice on this topic would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Access (VBA) has COM support, and makes heavy use of it. Any existing merchanting solution that works with COM can work with Access.

If your desired merchant solution doesn't, you can create COM classes and libraries in C#, C++, VB.Net and probably some more programming languages.

If it's a good idea? That heavily depends on your demands. I don't know what the advantage of an Access database over a program is for you.

Note that if you're using ASP.Net for your web solution, you might use a common class to check and authorize payments, and you might want to develop both simultaneously.